# Como ordenas y sumar un arreglo

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Este es el problema:

Dado un arreglo de N enteros, escribe un programa que procese una secuencia de M comandos de los siguientes tipos:

SUMA K: Sumar el entero K a todos los elementos del arreglo.
ORDENA: Ordenar el arreglo.

Esto es lo que tengo, pero no se muy bien como hacer la parte de la entrada de suma y ordena.

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
introducir el código aquí
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int n,m;
char operacion;
char ORDENA;
int suma;
int total = 0;

cin>>n;

int arr[n];

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
}

cin>>m;

for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
    cin>>operacion;
    
    if(operacion == ORDENA){
        sort(&arr[0],&arr[n]);
    }else{
        cin>>suma;
        total = arr[i] + suma;
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}
}
```

Este es un ejemplo de lo que se tiene que ingresar al porgrama y la salida en pantalla que tiene que salir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Link para ejecutar el código: https://www.onlinegdb.com/DFULKeSkd**

**Solución**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N, M;
    cout << "\n\tIngrese el numero de elementos del arreglo: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "\tIngrese el numero de comandos: ";
    cin >> M;
    vector<int> arr(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << "\tIngrese el elemento " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        string comando = "";
        cout << "\n\n\tIngrese el comando (SUMA / ORDENA): ";
        cin >> comando;
        if (comando == "SUMA") {
            int K;
            cout << "\tIngrese el valor K: ";
            cin >> K;
            cout << "\n\tArreglo nuevo: ";
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                arr[j] += K;
                cout << arr[j] << " ";
            }
        } else if (comando == "ORDENA") {
            sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
            cout << "\n\tArreglo ordenado: ";
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                cout << arr[j] << " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Una duda, para que sirve la linea del codigo : ` vector<int> arr(N);`?

Comment: @ed_sgs Declaro de esa manera el arreglo para poder trabajar adecuadamente con la función `sort`, que sirve para ordenar los elementos de menor a mayor.  Para ello, importo las librerias `vector` para el arreglo en cuestión y `algorithm` para usar la función `sort` en el arreglo.